# Why Event is not fired using Active x in C#?

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms to get the phone number from a caller ID which connected to COM port. The caller ID has `ActiveCID.ocx` file which I must use in my C# code to get the caller phone number when the phone rings. Using `ActiveCID.ocx` you can add the Computer Telephony Integration features of the Caller ID to any .NET application. Please, see the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I managed to add this `ActiveCID.ocx` component to my project and I wrote some code (I added `ActiveCID.ocx` from ToolBox --> right click --> choose items --> COM components).

The programs runs with no errors and I expect to see the caller phone number in the `richTextBox` when phone rings but the problem is that the Event is not fired when phone rings.

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Please help me. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ActiveCID1.Initialise();
        ActiveCID1.Port = 3;  // Port COM3 which the caller ID connected to
        ActiveCID1.IncomingCall += new EventHandler(HandlePhoneNumber);
    }

    public void HandlePhoneNumber(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = ActiveCID1.PhoneNumber;
    }

    private void ActiveCID1_IncomingCall(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to set up the port before you call initialize? Also do you have the correct event handler signature?

Comment: They're talking about VB sample code [here](http://www.crucible-technologies.co.uk/Help/Default.aspx?Page=ActiveCID), have you checked that? What Scott says sounds pretty obvious or maybe there is an additional `Open()` or `Start()` method you have to call, otherwise set the port (and other settings) before calling `Initialise()`...

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain . the initialize is for the ActiveCID component and according to the user guide of this caller ID: they say I only need to fellow 3 steps:    initialize , specify port number and handle the incomingCall event. sorry what do you mean by" correct event handler signature"? I am new to C#

Comment: @ Wouter Huysentruit. yes I already checked this page. the user guide of ActiveCID has some Delphi examples but not C# . the Delphi examples shows that I must  initialize the Active x component  , specify port number and then handle the incomingCall event, nothing more. In C#  you can not use Open() or Start() methods after ActiveCID instance. it sounds like I have to set the settings (speed, stopBit..) but  ActiveCID  should do that and I even can not create instance of ActiveCID to set those settings. any idea? thank you